gnuplot: boxplot over several files
In Gnuplot v5.4.2 I'd like to make a boxplots for several data columns from different files, combined in one multi-boxplot with the same y-value range.
What I can do is t combine the data into one file, however the columns do not have the same number of entries. Can I just specify NaN (not a number) or some other value and Gnuplot will ignore it?  For example, when the combined file looks like:
"label 1"  "label 2"  "label 3"
 12.3        44.2       13.3
 12.4        12.5       14.4
 11.6        13.7       NaN
 NaN         15.7       NaN


Can such data be used for a boxplot ?
Is it possible to tell to use the top row as labels?
How to also draw the mean values in addition to median and quantiles?

I had a look at http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_5.2/boxplot.html but the labels in files like silver.dat are hard-coded in the gplot script, and all data has the same number of rows.
Thank you.

Edit:
Stitching together pieces from boxplot.html,I now have this:
$DATA <<EOF
"label 1"  "label 2"  "label 3"
 11.3        14.2       11.3
 12.3        44.2       16.3
 1.4        12.5       14.4
 16.4        17.5       17.4
 17.4        12.5       14.4
 12.4        12.5       14.4
 11.6        13.7       NaN
 NaN         15.7       NaN
EOF

set terminal png size 400,300;
set output "box.png";

set key autotitle columnhead

factors = "\"label 1\"  \"label 2\"  \"label 3\""
NF = words(factors)

# No legend
unset key

# Solid box-and-whiskers where the whiskers extend 0%...100%
set style data boxplot
set style fill solid 0.5 border -1
set style boxplot fraction 1

set boxwidth  0.6
set xtic ("" 0)

set for [i=1:NF] xtics add (word(factors,i) i)

plot $DATA using (1):1, '' using (2):2, '' using (3):3 ;

Which produces:

what's pretty close to what I am after. For multiple files, I would use something like:
...
set xtics add ("label 1" 1)
set xtics add ("label 2" 2)

set yrange[-0.4 : *]
set xrange[0.5 : 2.5]

plot "file1.data" using (1):(23+$5) , \
     "file2.data" using (2):(23+$5);


I understand you want a boxplot from different files. Ok. So, do you want to combine the data into one file or do you think you have to combine the data into one file? What are the names of the different files and how does the data look like in these files? How do you want to specify the data you want to be plotted? e.g. from File1 column 6, from File2 column 3, and from File3 column 7?

I thought I had to combine it to one file, but I found how to use multiple files at once.  I extended my question accordingly. As far as the gplot script itself goes, I think I have to auto-generate it (the provided data files are already in the context of auto-generated).

The only question that remains is how to plot the mean values, too, e.g. as a horizontal, dashed line for each data set (not the mean over all sets). Presumably there is a boxplot option for that?

the line within the box is the mean value of the used dataset. What else do you want?

Huh? I though that the line in a boxplot is the median, not the mean? The mean might lie outside the 25%...75% quantile.

ouch, sorry, you are absolutely right. It's the median, not the mean. I will think about it and modify my answer to add the mean value.

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you want to plot boxplots from different files and different columns in one graph.
Somehow you have to specify the filenames and columns, e.g. in a string(list). So far, I haven't succeeded to use the xticlabels together with plotting style boxplot. So, the files is "plotted" a second time (actually, NaN is plotted, i.e. nothing) in order to get the corresponding columnheaders.
For further reading, check help boxplot, help word, help words, help xticlabels, help columnhead.
edit: added mean values to graph

use stats to calculate the mean value
put the values into an array
plot the array using plotting style with vectors

Check help stats, help arrays, help vectors.
Data:
SO78599002_1.dat
# SO78599002_1
File1Col1  File1Col2  File1Col3  File1Col4
 1         12         13         14
 2         22         23         24
 3         32         33         34
 4         42         43         44
 5         72         73         74
 6         82         83         84
 7         92         93         94

SO78599002_2.dat
# SO78599002_2
File2Col1  File2Col2  File2Col3
 1         12         13
 2         22         23
 3         32         33
 4         72         73
 5         82         83

SO78599002_3.dat
# SO78599002_3
File3Col1  File3Col2
 1         12
 2         22
 3         32
 4         42
 5         62
 6         72

Script:
### boxplots from different files and selected columns plus mean values
reset session

FILES   = "SO78599002_1.dat   SO78599002_2.dat   SO78599002_3.dat"
COLUMNS = "4   3   2"

N       = words(FILES)
File(i) = word(FILES,i) 
Col(i)  = int(word(COLUMNS,i))

set style fill solid 0.3
set key noautotitle

array MEANS[N] # set array size
do for [i=1:N] {
    stats File(i) u Col(i) nooutput
    MEANS[i] = STATS_mean
}

plot for [i=1:N] File(i)  u (i):Col(i) w boxplot, \
     for [i=1:N] File(i)  u (i):(NaN):xtic(columnhead(Col(i))) w p, \
     MEANS u ($0+1-0.25):2:(0.5):(0) w vec dt 2 lc "black" nohead ti "mean value" 
### end of script

Result:


One more question about setting the color. With ...  w boxplot lt rgb Farb(i) and Farb(i) = "red" it works, but when using the color like Farb(i) = word(FARBEN, i) and FARBEN="red #aabbcc" it throws "unrecognized color name and not a string". I tried adding " around the color using sprintf but with no avail.

@emacsdrivesmenuts I only get this error when I don't have enough colors specified. If you have 3 boxes but only 2 colors specified then I can reproduce this error.

oopsi, yes, my bad
